# Copy XValues from one TChartSeries to another

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, teechart

Does anyone know how to copy the XValues from one TChartSeries to another in Delphi7 (and TeeChart 4.04)? `TChartSeries.ReplaceList(CopySeries.XValues, OriginalSeries.XValues)` does not work, since it  seem to replace the reference, so when OriginalSeries is changed, so is CopySeries. The length of CopySeries is equal or greater than OriginalSeries. I want to preserve the CopySeries.YValues.

My workaround has been to create a temporary list

```
Dummy := TChartSeries.Create(nil);
Dummy.AssignValues(OriginalSeries);
CopySeries.ReplaceList(CopySeries.XValues, Dummy.XValues);
Dummy.YValues.Destroy;
```

but I get a memory leakage since I cannot Destroy the Dummy since that also removes the Dummy.XValues referenced by CopySeries.XValues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Assigning ValueList arrays directly to the series as in the [Real-time Charting](http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php) article, for example:

   ```
   uses Series;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues;
     Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self));

     { set our X array }
     Chart1[1].XValues.Value:=Chart1[0].XValues.Value;  { <-- the array }
     Chart1[1].XValues.Count:=Chart1[0].Count;          { <-- number of points }
     Chart1[1].XValues.Modified:=True;                  { <-- recalculate min and max }

     { set our Y array }
     Chart1[1].YValues.Value:=Chart1[0].YValues.Value;
     Chart1[1].YValues.Count:=Chart1[0].Count;
     Chart1[1].YValues.Modified:=True;

     { Show data }
     Chart1.Series[1].Repaint;
   end;
   ```
2. Clone series:

   ```
   uses Series;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues;
      Chart1.AddSeries(CloneChartSeries(Chart1[0]));
   end;
   ```
3. If you are using TeeChart 4.04 you'll probably have to address series like *Chart1.Series[0]* instead of *Chart1[0]* as in the *Repaint* call in the first example. Alternatively you could try something like this:

   ```
   uses Series, Math;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var i, MinNumValues, MaxNumValues: Integer;
   begin
     Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(15);
     Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(25);

     MinNumValues:=Min(Chart1.Series[0].Count, Chart1.Series[1].Count);
     MaxNumValues:=Max(Chart1.Series[0].Count, Chart1.Series[1].Count);

     for i:=0 to MinNumValues -1 do
       Chart1.Series[1].XValue[i]:=Chart1.Series[0].XValue[i];

     for i:=MinNumValues to MaxNumValues-1 do
       Chart1.Series[1].ValueColor[i] := clNone;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I forgot to mention that I am using Delphi7 and TeeChart 4.04, so it seems like I am unable to use the syntax: `Value := Chart1.Series[0].XValues.Value.` I also cannot use the CloneChartSeries, since I want to preserve the YValues.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just did that as well. It seems code formatting in a list works a little bit different than usual...

Comment: I get `[Error] '[' expected but := found` on the syntax `Value := ...`

Comment: @Truls Ok, I added a third solution option for TeeChart 4.04. What about that?

Comment: Solution 3: Works perfectly as long as the Series.XValues have the same length, but they (generally) differ. So if I am using that approach I'll have to delete the rest of the XValues-array.

Comment: @Truls what about solution 3 now? I have modified the code a little bit to change XValues for the number of values of the "smallest" series. If necessary I could try to find a "clean" Delphi 7 install.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet Almost. After the copy there should be the same amount of Values in the new XValues-array as the old, since otherwise the new one will print out too many points.

Comment: @Truls Ok, I extended solution #3 to remove remaining points.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3724/discussion-between-truls-and-narcis-calvet)